# Apache 2.4: First VirtualHost configuration loading for ServerNames of other vhosts

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I have a problem with VirtualHosts which Apache 2.4.

If I navigate to ty1.dev, I get the site for af2.dev instead

If this was Apache 2.2, all I would need to add is `NameVirtualHost *:80` but is ignored in 2.4.

error.log does not report any problems

What have I missed?

```
# httpd-vhosts.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName af2.dev
    ServerAlias af2.dev
    ServerAdmin user@host.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/Users/Adam.Adam-PC/Sites/af2/web"
    <Directory c:/Users/Adam.Adam-PC/Sites/af2/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ty1.dev
    ServerAlias ty1.dev
    ServerAdmin user@host.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/Users/Adam.Adam-PC/Sites/ty1"
    <Directory c:/Users/Adam.Adam-PC/Sites/ty1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do you get from `c:\path\to\apache.exe -S`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting a specific ip and port in your listen statement as well as your virtualhost blocks. So put:

```
listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

and in each of your virtualhost:

```
<virtualhost 127.0.0.1:80>
```

Answer (score -1):

0
down vote

I find answer from here: http://alexking.org/blog/2007/11/01/apache-2-only-serves-first-virtual-host

Put 2 servername in same 1 VirtualHost tag as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName beta-site-1.com

DocumentRoot “/Library/WebServer/beta-site-1”

ServerName beta-site-2.com

DocumentRoot “/Library/WebServer/beta-site-2”

</VirtualHost>
```

I ended up having issues with the second site because I had two VirtualHost tag blocks.